# Monochrome printing fails on an Epson Workforce 3620 from Windows 10

Tags: printing, epson-workforce

I want to print a color document in black and white. on a relatively new [Epson WorkForce 3620](https://epson.com/For-Work/Printers/Inkjet/Epson-WorkForce-WF-3620-All-in-One-Printer/p/C11CD19201) from an HP PC running Windows 10.

The information said to click the color tab under print preferences, but there is no color tab under print preferences; only layout and paper/quality tabs.

Color also does not print correctly.  The printer used to work fine, until about two weeks ago.

Comment: Have you accepted these security updates? https://epson.com/Support/wa00826 Please check by clicking the Start or Windows key, do `Updates`, and have your PC check for an update. Please click [edit] after you have done so and let us know if they are still waiting to download or install, or if there's an installation failure message.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try reinstalling the printer.

Go to Devices and Printers and remove the Printer device. 
Still in Devices and Printers, click once on any other print device to expose the Printer Server manager tab. Click on that and then the Driver Tab.
Remove the Driver.

Now restart the computer, install the newest printer driver and test.

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: Be sure you're installing the model-specific driver from the manufacturer. Missing functionality usually means the wrong driver has been installed.